# Check if value exists in the database which is selected column ASP.NET C#

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I want to check whether "jin" exists in the database.

But I could now find true sign in my ASP.NET.

I think that mean I cannot find "jin" in the first second column,

I put Time table.

My code is not working.. help me.

[image]

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=IT\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Gentl;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=sjin101!";
con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "select * From Time";
cmd.Connection = con;

SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (rd.Read())
{
    if (rd[1].ToString() == "jin")
    {
        flag = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (flag == true)
{
    TextBox1.Text = "Find";
}
else
    TextBox1.Text = "no";
```

Comment: The table shown has columns called "11:00AM", "11:30AM" - is that correct? I'm just wondering if you could change the cmd.CommandText so that you select all the columns by name, to be sure to know what is the content of rd[1]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search for `jin` in all columns at once, one option is to unpivot the columns to rows, then do conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when x.val = 'jin' then 1 else 0 end) found
from time t
cross apply (values
    ([11:00AM]),
    ([11:30AM]),
    ([12:00PM]),
    ([12:30PM]),
    ...
) x(val)
```

This produces a scalar resultset(a single row and a single column) called `found`, that contains `1` if the value exists anywhere in the columns listed in the `values()` row constructor, and `0` if it doesn't.

Comment: @SangYongJin: whenever possible, it is always more efficient to do the computation in the database rather than select everything, then loop in your application...

Comment: @SangYongJin . . . Your question is tagged with two database tags and asp.net.  There is no C# tag at all.  I would suggest that you accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can include the check for "jin" directly in the query, and once it is executed, you can check if the sqldatareader has any rows.

I have only included the first two columns in the below example but you can include the rest.

```html
       SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
       con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=IT\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Gentl;Persist 
       Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=sjin101!";
       con.Open();

       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
       cmd.CommandText = "select * From Time where 11:00AM= \"jin\" or 12:00AM = \"jin\"";
       cmd.Connection = con;

       SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

       if(rd.HasRows()) {
           TextBox1.Text = "Find";
       }
       else
           TextBox1.Text = "no";
```